# Comparing All Columns That Share A Common Identifier in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Good day all.
I'm working on doing a comparison of records query and am having trouble finding an easier way to do it. Here's the run down:

Essentially, two people I work with have been entering data so each participant in our study will have two records in our database. I have to do a comparison of these records and return all discrepancies so they can be examined and fixed upon further review. Cannot think of an easy way to do this - there are a hefty amount of fields and I'd rather avoid having to do a comparison of each column manually.

Is there a method to compare from the following:
[image: testdata]

I'd want to compare all columns where Participant ID is the same. End goal is to make one column of all discrepancies per Participant.

Any ideas? My first attempt involved pulling all records where Count(Participant ID)>1 and then joined this on all the tables we're examining. As such, each participant had 2 rows - one for each extraction that was entered into the database. I then made these records side by side into one row so there was aType_1, bType_1, aType_2, bType_2, etc. I then began writing comparisons for each individual column pair, eg. aType_1<>bType_1, and returning the ID. This would effectively require a lot of coding and a massive set of union queries if I want to condense into a list of discrepancies. I cannot think of a simple way to do this... Thank you in advance for any ideas! :)

Comment: We don't know what `aQ1<>bQ1` means. Share some sample data and what exactly you're trying to compare within that data. I think that will help people formulate answers.

Comment: @OverMind - added a table for viewing - Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier column (a primary key maybe) in your participant-data table?

Comment: @keithxm23 Hi Keith - yes, each record has its own primary key, didn't include in sample data, but definitely there!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand what you want.

`SELECT a.Type_1, b.Type_1, a.Type_2, b.Type_2` etc. 
`FROM table a` 
`INNER JOIN table b ON b.ParticipantID = a.ParticipantID` 
`WHERE a.Type_1<>b.Type_1 AND a.Type_2<>b.Type_2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is how far I managed to get. Not very far from what you managed I guess. But here goes anything. (Oh and this is in MySql >_<)

Assuming your participant-data table has some kind of unique valued column (primary key?), you could do something like the following:

If this is your table structure:

```
mysql> describe foo;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type1 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type2 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type3 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pk    | int(11) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And you have data as follows:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| pid  | type1 | type2 | type3 | pk   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|    1 |    14 |    24 |    34 |    1 |
|    1 |    15 |    24 |    34 |    2 |
|    2 |    15 |    24 |    34 |    3 |
|    2 |    15 |    25 |    34 |    4 |
|    3 |    15 |    25 |    34 |    5 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following query returns a comparison of rows with matching pids:

```
mysql> select  a.pid, a.type1 <> b.type1 as t1, a.type2 <> b.type2 as t2, a.type3 <> b.type3 as t3 from foo a join foo b on a.pid = b.pid where a.pk != b.pk group by a.pid having count(a.pid) > 1;
+------+------+------+------+
| pid  | t1   | t2   | t3   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|    2 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Same query, including the original column values for reference:

```
mysql> select *, a.pid, a.type1 <> b.type1 as t1, a.type2 <> b.type2 as t2, a.type3 <> b.type3 as t3 from foo a join foo b on a.pid = b.pid where a.pk != b.pk group by a.pid having count(a.pid) > 1;
+------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| pid  | type1 | type2 | type3 | pk   | pid  | type1 | type2 | type3 | pk   | pid  | t1   | t2   | t3   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    15 |    24 |    34 |    2 |    1 |    14 |    24 |    34 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|    2 |    15 |    25 |    34 |    4 |    2 |    15 |    24 |    34 |    3 |    2 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you somehow want to avoid writing down the name of each column (because you have 100s) you would want to consider using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table to get the column names via a stored procedure maybe. Again this is MySql, but I'm sure MS-Access has an equivalent table.

Hope this helps at least a bit. :P

Answer (score 0):

are you familiar with VBA?  When I had to implement a solution similar to yours, I iterated through the fields collection of one entry's recordset and compared it with the value in field in the same ordinal position of the 2nd entry's recordset.

```
    dim db as database
    dim rs1 as recordset
    dim rs2 as recordset
    dim i as integer
    dim bSame as boolean

    bsame = true  ' init
    set rs1 = db.openrecordset("qryEntry1")
    set rs2 = db.openrecordset("qryEntry2")
    for i = 0 to rs1.fields.count
       bSame = bSame and ( rs1(i) = rs2(i) )
    next
```

here's the actual code I used:

```
Public Function verify(sPatientID As String) As Boolean
' returns true if all fields for entries 1 and 2 match'
    Dim db As Database
    Dim qdef As QueryDef
    Dim rsDemo1 As Recordset
    Dim rsDemo2 As Recordset
    Dim rsDemoDiffs As Recordset
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim iDifferCountTestValues As Integer
    Dim iDifferCountDemo As Integer
    Dim iField As Integer
    Dim bDiffers As Boolean
    Dim bDemoEntered As Boolean
    Dim bValuesEntered As Boolean
    Dim bActive As Boolean
    Dim bWithdrawn As Boolean
    Dim bGroupSet As Boolean

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblPatient where patientID = '" & sPatientID & "'")
    bActive = rs("isActive")
    bWithdrawn = rs("isWithdrawn")
    bGroupSet = (rs("groupID") > 0)

    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qryClearEntriesDifferPerPatient")
    qdef.Parameters("patientIDCrit") = sPatientID
    qdef.Execute

    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qrySetEntry1DiffersForPatient")
    qdef.Parameters("patientIDCrit") = sPatientID
    qdef.Execute

    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qrySetEntry2DiffersForPatient")
    qdef.Parameters("patientIDCrit") = sPatientID
    qdef.Execute

    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qryTestValueEntriesDifferForPatient")
    qdef.Parameters("patientIDCrit") = sPatientID
    Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset
    bValuesEntered = Not rs.EOF
    If rs.EOF Then
        iDifferCountTestValues = 0
    Else
        iDifferCountTestValues = Abs(rs(1))     ' sum of true values is negative'
    End If

    db.Execute "Delete from tblDemographicEntriesDiffer where patientID = '" & sPatientID & "'"
    Set rsDemo1 = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblPatientDemographics where patientID = '" & sPatientID & "' and entryID = 1")
    Set rsDemo2 = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblPatientDemographics where patientID = '" & sPatientID & "' and entryID = 2")
    bDemoEntered = (Not rsDemo1.EOF) And (Not rsDemo2.EOF)
    Set rsDemoDiffs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblDemographicEntriesDiffer")
    For iField = 2 To rsDemo1.Fields.Count - 1      ' skip comparison of entryID'
        If rsDemo1.Fields(iField).Value <> rsDemo2.Fields(iField).Value Then
            bDiffers = True
        ElseIf IsNull(rsDemo1.Fields(iField)) And Not IsNull(rsDemo2.Fields(iField)) Then
            bDiffers = True
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rsDemo1.Fields(iField)) And IsNull(rsDemo2.Fields(iField)) Then
            bDiffers = True
        Else
            bDiffers = False
        End If
        If bDiffers Then
            rsDemoDiffs.AddNew
            rsDemoDiffs("patientID") = sPatientID
            rsDemoDiffs("fieldName") = rsDemo1.Fields(iField).Name
            rsDemoDiffs("entry1") = rsDemo1.Fields(iField).Value
            rsDemoDiffs("entry2") = rsDemo2.Fields(iField).Value
            rsDemoDiffs.Update
        End If
    Next

    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qryDemoDiffersCountForPatient")
    qdef.Parameters("patientIDCrit") = sPatientID
    Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset
    If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
        iDifferCountDemo = 0
    Else
        iDifferCountDemo = rs(1)
    End If

    verify = (iDifferCountTestValues + iDifferCountDemo = 0) And bDemoEntered And bActive
    If bWithdrawn Then
        verify = verify And bGroupSet
    Else
        verify = verify And bValuesEntered
    End If
    db.Execute "Update tblPatient set isVerified = " & verify & " where patientID = '" & sPatientID & "'"

    rsDemo1.Close
    rsDemo2.Close
    rsDemoDiffs.Close
    db.Close
End Function
```